# How to make tree structured text editor in Qt/Pyqt?

Tags: qt, text-editor, pyqt

can you advice what to use for making tree structured text editor?

I used QTreeView for this (asked few questions to solve my problems), but it seams it's not suitable for this purpose.

Thanks in advance,

Serge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "tree structured text editor"?

`QTreeView` itself is hardly suitable for an editor, but it can be used to select which files to edit/show. So you can have two main widgets: on the left a tree with files/directories, and on the right a text editor widget such as [QTextEdit](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/qtextedit.html#details) for the editing itself.

Comment: i need usual text editor, but with a feature to hide rows that belongs to upper level row

Comment: @serge: this isn't directly supported. Try more complex widgets, like QScintilla (http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/qscintilla/intro)